# Applying Fermat’s Little Theorem to $g^\frac{p-1}{2}$ (mod $p$).

Tags: number-theory

I am struggling to spot how $\left(g^a\right)^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv g^\frac{p-1}{2} (\mod{p})$ when $p$ is prime greater than $3$, $a$ is odd and $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

How does Fermat’s Little Theorem allow us to drop the power of $a$ in this congruence?

Comment: You can also prove it simply by observing that $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod {p}$ and $(g^{\frac{p-1}{2}})^a\equiv (-1)^a\pmod {p}$.

Comment: @user31415: You should put that in an answer, adding an explanation of why that's the case when $g$ is a primitive root of $p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a = 2k+1$.

$$(g^a)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = g^{a\frac{p-1}{2}} = g^{(p-1)\frac{2k+1}{2}} = g^{(p-1)(k+\frac{1}{2})} = g^{(p-1)k}\cdot g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \stackrel{*}{=} g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod{p}$$

Where Fermat's Little Theorem is used in $*$

Comment: PS When $g$ is a primitive root $g^{(p-1)/2}$ will always be $-1$.

Comment: ie  $\ (1\!+\!kd)(m/d) \equiv m/d\pmod m\ $ Here $\ d=2,\ m = p\!-\!1\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

$ \color{#c00}{c^2\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, c^{\large 1+2k}\!\equiv c\color{#c00}{(c^{\large 2})}^{\large k}\!\equiv c\color{#c00}{(1)}^k\!\equiv c\ \ \ $ [OP $ $ is $\ \ a = 1\!+\!2k,\,\ c \equiv g^{(p-1)/2}\pmod p$]

---

**Remark** $\ $ Generally if $\, c^n = 1\, $ then exponents on $\,c\,$ can be taken mod $\,n\,$ (above $\,n=2)$

**Lemma** $\ \ \color{#c00}{c^{\large n} = 1}\ $ and  $\ i\equiv j\pmod{n}\ \Rightarrow\ c^{\large i} = c^{\large j}$

**Proof** $\ \ i = j\! +\! kn\,\Rightarrow\, c^{\large i} = c^{\large j+kn} = c^{\large j}(\color{#c00}{c^{\large n}})^{\large k} = c^{\large j}\color{#c00}1^{\large k} = c^{\large j}$

Comment: Note that the proof needs only that $\,p\nmid g\,$ since then $\,c^2\equiv g^{p-1}\equiv 1\,$ by little Fermat.